# Handlebars #if not working inside #forEach

Tags: if-statement, foreach, handlebars.js, helper

I need to render a table, with links that will be displayed if the user has admin rights. I have a #forEach and inside it, an {{#if isAdmin}}. isAdmin is a helper that for the moment simply returns true or false. If I render {{isAdmin}} it displays the value correctly (true, false) but if I try to evaluate it with {{#if}} nothing happens. My code:

Nodejs custom helper:

```
var hbs = handlebars.create({
        partialsDir: [
            'view/partials/'
        ],
        helpers:{
            isAdmin: function(){
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML - HANDLEBARS

```
{{#forEach eventData}}      
<tr>
    <td>{{@index}}</td>
    <td>{{general_name}}</td>
    <td>{{general_description}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/view/{{_id}}">View</a>            
        {{#if isAdmin}}
        <a href="/versions/{{_id}}">Details & Changes</a>
        {{/if}}
    </td>
</tr>    
{{/forEach}}
```

The link "Details & Changes" is never displayed. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered that I can access variables outside the forEach by using the following syntax:

```
{{../foo}} or {{#myhelper ../myfoo}}
```

Helper

```
h.registerHelper('isAdmin', function(username, options) {
  var admins = 'admin';
    if(admins.includes (username)) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }else{
        return options.inverse(this);  
    }
});


h.registerHelper('isCreator', function(logged_in, created_by, options) {
    if(logged_in == created_by) {
        return options.fn(this);
    }else{
        return options.inverse(this);  
    }
});
```

Handlebars

```
{{#forEach eventData}}      
    <tr>
        <td>{{@index}}</td>
        <td>{{general_name}}</td>
        <td>{{general_description}}</td>
        <td>{{submited_by}}</td>
        <td>{{general_setup_by}} | {{general_register_by}}</td>    
        <td>{{general_time_start}} | {{general_time_end}}</td>    
        <td>{{layout_room}}</td>        
        {{#isAdmin ../username}}
            <td><a href="/versions/{{id}}">Details & Changes</a></td>    
        {{else}}
        {{#isCreator ../username updated_by}}            
            <td><a href="/event/{{id}}">Edit</a></td>
            {{else}}
            <td><a href="/view/{{id}}">View</a></td>
        {{/isCreator}}
        {{/isAdmin}}
    </tr>    
{{/forEach}}
```